# Copy files from local PC to SAS server in Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I need to extract a particular sheet from a .xls file on my local machine and get it as a .sas7bdat files on the SAS server on which I work (or the other way round, that is, import it and then convert).

The problem is that although this can be done using the Import Wizard, I **need to do this using the 'Copy Files Add-in'** because it needs to be built as a part of an automated process.

When I tried doing this using the copy files add-in, it DID copy the .xls file onto the server according to the log, but the **.xls file didn't actually show in the library and could not be referenced either (or maybe I'm just referencing it wrongly)**.

This has led me to believe that I need to convert it to a .sas7bdat and then import it.

Is there a way to get past this? Please bear in mind that I am talking about an automated process, so the wizard is useless for me (or is it? I'm not sure)

NOTE : I am extremely sorry that I cannot post the log and screenshots here, because I work as an offshore resource for a very large bank and cannot post anything here. I have, however, tried to make my problem as clear as possible. If any further clarifications are needed, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've read [There and Back Again](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/12/06/copy-files-in-sas-eg/) which covers this in some detail.

Ultimately, all you're doing is copying the excel file as a file onto the SAS server. You're not importing it into a SAS dataset.  You would import it by placing the file (either the remote file after copy files add-in, or the local file) in the workflow as an import step.

For example, if you chose `/usr/lib/sasdata/myexcel.xls` as the remote copy destination, you then need to include that file in your workflow as an import step (you can drag/drop the file and it will automatically create that step for you, with some wizardry).

Comment: Here's the real problem. You say that I can drag and drop the file after it has been copied onto the server into my workflow. However, even though the log says its been copied there, it does not show there (even as a .xls). Are you saying that if I add an import step, it will show up as a dataset?

Comment: You need to import the xls (either in a program `proc import` or in an import step), yes.